Problemas al realizar un reporte en Android Studio
Muy buenas amigos y amigas de la comunidad, esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, miren terminando mi primera app de Android para realizar reportes en pdf y ser enviados posteriormente, este es el código que estoy utilizando actualmente en el cual consiste se le da la opción  al usuario de opciones "Si", "No" y Cancelar", en este caso es el que corresponde al "Si".
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setMessage("¿Este Presupuesto es con Mano de Obra C/ Valores y Repuestos C/Valores.?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Sí", (dialog, id) -> {
                    try {
                        InputStream jasperStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.presupuesto3);
                        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
                        parameters.put("patente", txtpatente.getText().toString());
                        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperStream, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());

                        // Crear el documento PDF
                        Document document = new Document();
                        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/informe.pdf"));
                        document.open();

                        // Crear una fuente personalizada para Arial Black (usando Typeface)
                        Typeface arialBlackTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Arial-Black.ttf");
                        BaseFont arialBlackBaseFont = BaseFont.createFont("assets/Arial-Black.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                        com.itextpdf.text.Font arialBlackFont = new com.itextpdf.text.Font(arialBlackBaseFont, 24);

                        // Crear una fuente personalizada para Times New Roman Bold (usando Typeface)
                        Typeface timesNewRomanBoldTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Times-New-Roman-Bold.ttf");
                        BaseFont timesNewRomanBoldBaseFont = BaseFont.createFont("assets/Times-New-Roman-Bold.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                        com.itextpdf.text.Font timesNewRomanBoldFont = new com.itextpdf.text.Font(timesNewRomanBoldBaseFont, 10);

                        // Crear una fuente personalizada para Times New Roman (usando Typeface)
                        Typeface timesNewRomanTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Times-New-Roman.ttf");
                        BaseFont timesNewRomanBaseFont = BaseFont.createFont("assets/Times-New-Roman.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                        com.itextpdf.text.Font timesNewRomanFont = new com.itextpdf.text.Font(timesNewRomanBaseFont, 10);

                        // Asignar las fuentes a las diferentes partes del reporte
                        Paragraph title = new Paragraph("Presupuesto", arialBlackFont); // Título en Arial Black
                        document.add(title);

                        Paragraph companyClient = new Paragraph("Compañía/Cliente", timesNewRomanBoldFont); // Encabezado en Times New Roman Bold
                        document.add(companyClient);

                        // Crear una tabla para los detalles
                        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3); // Ejemplo con 3 columnas
                        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Detalle del Presupuesto", timesNewRomanFont));
                        table.addCell(cell);
                        document.add(table);

                        // Agregar más contenido según sea necesario...

                        // Cerrar el documento
                        document.close();

                        // Exportar el reporte a PDF con iText
                        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
                        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
                        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/informe.pdf"));
                        SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
                        exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
                        exporter.exportReport();

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Reporte generado exitosamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (JRException | DocumentException | IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error al generar el reporte", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

al momento de ejecutarlo hago click en el botón del imprimir y me tira hacia afuera de la app del cual me arrojan estos errores:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.gestion, PID: 10342
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Font;
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveObject(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.checkResolve(ObjectInputStream.java:1490)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1442)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2186)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2110)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1935)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1442)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2186)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:560)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport.readObject(JRBaseReport.java:777)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1109)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2085)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1935)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1442)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:278)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:262)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:737)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:1061)
    at com.example.gestion.archivos.ingreso.lambda$imprimirReporte$4$com-example-gestion-archivos-ingreso(ingreso.java:1515)
    at com.example.gestion.archivos.ingreso$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:188)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.awt.Font" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.gestion/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~sVYx38bSQ9ISRH9ShL85ZQ==/com.example.gestion-PRw9LPVgKdFcU8J_kkVAog==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~sVYx38bSQ9ISRH9ShL85ZQ==/com.example.gestion-PRw9LPVgKdFcU8J_kkVAog==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveObject(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:121) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.checkResolve(ObjectInputStream.java:1490) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1442) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2186) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2110) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1935) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1442) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2186) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:560) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport.readObject(JRBaseReport.java:777) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1109) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2085) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1935) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1442) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:278) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:262) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:737) 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:1061) 
    at com.example.gestion.archivos.ingreso.lambda$imprimirReporte$4$com-example-gestion-archivos-ingreso(ingreso.java:1515) 
    at com.example.gestion.archivos.ingreso$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.onClick(Unknown Source:2) 
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:188) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135) 
    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10342 SIG: 9
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:52684', transport: 'socket'

investigando en la web es que la clase java.awt.Font no es compatible con Android, pero a su vez averiguando realice estas dependencias para que no halla problema.
dependencies {
// iText library: Usamos una única versión compatible con JasperReports 6.17.0
implementation ('com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.13.2') {
    exclude group: 'org.bouncycastle' // Excluye posibles conflictos
}
// JasperReports: Aseguramos la misma versión para todos los módulos
implementation 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.17.0'
implementation 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-fonts:6.17.0'
// Otras dependencias de Android
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', includes: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.6.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.11'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:3.0.2'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.7.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.7.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.7.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.7.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.7.0"
// Testing
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'

}
llevo varios días en esto y no he podido solucionar dicho problema, ya que soy novato en estas lides de Android, si me pueden ayudar con esto se les agradecería enormemente, desde ya muchas gracias
